# Prove that $a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da} \geq \pi$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c,d >0$, and $a+b+c+d=4$, prove that 
>   $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da} \geq \pi.$$

I don't think Jensen's inequality will help here, but I think first determining where equality holds will be useful. Maybe taking the logarithm or exponential of both sides will also be useful, but I want to in the end get rid of the plus signs in order to simplify it.

Comment: This reminds me the inequality [$a^a+b^b>a^b+b^a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Examples) from Wikipédia. Not sure if it help though...

Comment: May I ask how you came across this problem? Also, do you know whether the constant $\pi$ is optimal?

Comment: @Wojowu It is from a problem solving website. Yes, I believe equality is achieved.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/u289943h1238522p6313199

Comment: So the best there seems to be $0.28,0.4479,3.272,0.0001$ giving $3.16075$.

Comment: @almagest So equality is not achieved?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Who knows! It depends on whether you believe xlzq. Several of the people on that part of the site are good. It is the olympiad training part.

Comment: @almagest Mathematica finds `{3.16059, {a -> 0.445458, b -> 3.27945, c -> 1.74611*10^-7, d -> 0.275088}}`

Comment: The best I've got out of Mathematica is `3.1605859174508652189…`, using `NMinimize[{(a^2)^(a^2 b^2) + (b^2)^(b^2 c^2) + (c^2)^(c^2 d^2) + \
(d^2)^(d^2 a^2), 
  a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 && 
   a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 == 4}, {a, b, c, d}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

Comment: @PatrickStevens So that means equality might be achievable?

Comment: @Puzzled417 The fact that I couldn't make Mathematica do better than that is (very) weak evidence against "equality is achievable", since Mathematica can only output $\pi$ if $\pi$ is achievable, and it did not output $\pi$.

Comment: Alright, did I fall for a "scam", i.e. someone cooked up a function and figured out a numeric lower bound? I found the original post on [artofproblemsolving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1238522_aabbbcccddda_geqslant_pi)  and it seems the original poster was banned from the site. Is there an actual solution to this problem?

Comment: An interesting inequality, but even without the numerical evidence for the bound being around $3.16$ there doesn't seem to be any reason for $\pi$ to feature here. Seems arbitrary

Comment: @PatrickStevens, it's interesting that the function seems minimized with $c$ slightly above 0, and that taking the limit to $c=0$ does not increase it.

Comment: Wrote a simple program to find a naive lower bound within various rectangular prisms in the search space; if I haven't made any mistakes in my code, it's shown that any solutions less than $3.1416$ must have at least one term less than $1/30$. Handling very small inputs is a little tough, though.

Comment: As some users pointed out, WLOG, by letting $d=\max(a,b,c,d)$, the best is $a=0, \cdots$. The difficulty may arise from $a=0$ when using bounds.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** The inequality has been proven for all cases except the following five:

- $1 < a < 2$, $b < 1$, $c > 1$, $d < 1$
- $1 < a < 2$, $b < 1$, $c < 1$, $d < 1$
- $2 < a < 3$, $b < 0.207$, $c > 1$, $d < 1$
- $2 < a < 3$, $b < 0.256$, $c < 1$, $d < 1$
- $3 < a < 4$, $b < 0.129$, $c < 1$, $d < 1$

---

This partial answer heavily uses the results that for a real number $k>0$,

> - $\min x^{kx}=(\sqrt[e]{e^k})^{-1}$,
> - $k^{kx}>k^{kx_0}$ for $k>1$ and $x>x_0$,
> - $k^{kx}<k^{kx_0}$ for $k<1$ and $x>x_0$.

As the sum $$S=a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}$$ is cyclic, we need only concern $a=1$ and $a>1$ to prove the truth of the inequality. Thus there are sixteen cases that we need to consider (note that in most cases the condition $a+b+c+d=4$ is implicitly used).

> $1)$ $a=b=c=d=1$

Clearly $S=1+1+1+1>\pi$.

> $2)$ $a=b=1$, $c>1$, $d<1$

As $c<2$, $S>1+1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $3)$ $a=b=1$, $c<1$, $d>1$

As $d<2$, $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1>\pi$.

> $4)$ $a=1$, $b>1$, $c>1$, $d<1$

We have $S>1+1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $5)$ $a=1$, $b>1$, $c<1$, $d>1$

As $d<2$, $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1>\pi$.

> $6)$ $a=1$, $b>1$, $c<1$, $d<1$

We have $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $7)$ $a=1$, $b<1$, $c>1$, $d<1$

If $b\ge0.6$, $c\le2.4$ so $S\ge1+0.6^{0.6\cdot2.4}+1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}>\pi$. If $b<0.6$, $c>1.4$ so $S>1+(\sqrt[e]{e^3})^{-1}+\min\{1.4^{1.4d}+d^d\}>\pi$.

> $8)$ $a=1$, $b<1$, $c<1$, $d>1$

If $b\ge0.89$, $d\le2.11$ so $S\ge1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^{2.11}})^{-1}+1>\pi$. If $b<0.89$, $3>d>1.11$ so $S\ge 1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^3})^{-1}+1.11^{1.11}>\pi$.

> $9)$ $a=1$, $b<1$, $c>1$, $d>1$

As $c<2$, $S>1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1+1>\pi$.

> $10)$ $a>1$, $b>1$, $c>1$, $d<1$

As $a<2$, $S>1+1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $11)$ $a>1$, $b>1$, $c<1$, $d>1$

As $d<2$, $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1>\pi$.

> $12)$ $a>1$, $b>1$, $c<1$, $d<1$

If $d\ge0.675$, $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^{0.675}})^{-1}+0.675^{0.675}>\pi$. If $a\ge2$, $d<0.675$, then $S>2^2+0+0+0>\pi$. If $a<2$, $d<0.675$, then $S>1+1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $13)$ $a>1$, $b<1$, $c>1$, $d<1$

If $3>a>2$, $c<2$ so $b\ge0.207$, $S>2^{2\cdot0.207}+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1+(\sqrt[e]{e^3})^{-1}>\pi$.

> $14)$ $a>1$, $b<1$, $c<1$, $d>1$

If $d\ge2$, $S>0+0+0+2^2>\pi$. If $d<2$, $S>1+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1>\pi$.

> $15)$ $a>1$, $b<1$, $c>1$, $d>1$

As $c<2$, $S>1+(\sqrt[e]{e^2})^{-1}+1+1>\pi$.

> $16)$ $a>1$, $b<1$, $c<1$, $d<1$

If $4>a>3$, $b\ge0.129$, $S>3^{3\cdot0.129}+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^4})^{-1}>\pi$. If $3>a>2$, $b\ge0.256$, $S>2^{2\cdot0.256}+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e})^{-1}+(\sqrt[e]{e^3})^{-1}>\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Warning : It's a partial proof but I think it's interesting .
We have the following theorem :

> Let $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd\geq e^{-2}$ then we have :
>   $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}\geq 4(e^{-0.5})^{e^{-1}}$$

Proof :
We begin to apply AM-GM to get :
$$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}\geq 4(a^{ab}b^{bc}c^{cd}d^{da})^{0.25}$$
Hence we want to prove :
$$4(a^{ab}b^{bc}c^{cd}d^{da})^{0.25}\geq 4(e^{-0.5})^{e^{-1}}$$
Now we take the logarithm :
$$0.25\sum_{cyc}ab\ln(a)\geq -0.5e^{-1}$$

But $x\ln(x)$ is convex so we get :
$$0.25\sum_{cyc}ab\ln(a)\geq 0.25(ab+bc+cd+da)\ln(\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{a+b+c+d})$$

Hence we want to prove :

$$0.25(ab+bc+cd+da)\ln(\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{a+b+c+d})\geq -0.5e^{-1}$$

Wich is true because :
$$\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{a+b+c+d}\geq e^{-0.5}$$

And

$$a+b+c+d\geq 4e^{-1}$$

Now remains to add the condition $a+b+c+d=4$ to get :

> Let $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd\geq e^{-2}$ and $a+b+c+d=4$ then we have :
>   $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}> 4(e^{-0.5})^{e^{-1}}$$

An other idea will be to extend the initial theorem (using the same technique) and see what happend .

Finally we conclude with the fact that it completes partialy the result of TheSimpliFire .

Comment: Why $\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{a+b+c+d}\geq e^{-0.5}$? Why this and $a+b+c+d\geq 4e^{-1}$ (by the way, since $abcd\ge e^-2$ then AM-GM implies $a+b+c+d\geq 4e^{-1/2}$) imply $0.25(ab+bc+cd+da)\ln(\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{a+b+c+d})\geq -0.5e^{-1}$? Note, that a priori the logarithm may be negative, so we have to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily prove a weaker inequality as follows. It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Examples) that if $x>0$ then $x^x\ge \left(\tfrac 1e\right)^{1/e}=E$. Since the original inequality is cyclic, witout loss of generality we can assume that $d\ge 1$. Then

$$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}\ge E^b+E^c+E^d+1^a\ge 3E^{(b+c+d)/3}+1\ge 
3E^{4/3}+1>2.8369.$$

Answer (score 1):

With computer, we can use the branch and bound strategy to prove the inequality.

**Proof**: The inequality is written as
$$F(a, b, c, d) = \mathrm{e}^{ba\ln a} + \mathrm{e}^{cb\ln b} + \mathrm{e}^{dc\ln c} + \mathrm{e}^{a d\ln d} > \pi.$$

We first introduce some auxiliary results (Facts 1 through 2). The proofs are given later.

*Fact 1*: Given four real numbers $0 \le A < B, \ 0 \le C < D$ with $B-A \le \frac{1}{8}, \ D-C\le \frac{1}{8}$. Let $x\in [A, B]$ and $y\in [C, D]$. For convenience, we set $0\ln 0 = 0$. We have

i) If $\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} \in [A, B]$, then $yx\ln x \ge -D \mathrm{e}^{-1}$;

ii) If $\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} \notin [A, B]$ and $ A < 1$, then $yx\ln x \ge D \min(A\ln A, B\ln B)$;

iii) If $A \ge 1$, then $yx\ln x \ge C A \ln A$.

*Fact 2*: If $a\in [0, 1], \ b \in [0, 2], \ c \in [0, 1], \ d\ge 0$ and $a+b+c+d=4$, then $F(a,b,c,d) > \pi$.

Now let us proceed. WLOG, assume that $d= \max(a,b,c,d)$. Clearly $b \le 2$.

If $a > 1$, we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{ba\ln a} + \mathrm{e}^{cb\ln b} + \mathrm{e}^{dc\ln c} + \mathrm{e}^{a d\ln d} \ge 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(cb\ln b + dc\ln c)} + 2
\ge 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{3}{\mathrm{e}})} + 2 > \pi$$
since $x\ln x \ge -\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$ for all $x > 0$, and $x\mapsto \mathrm{e}^x$ is convex.

If $c > 1$, we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{ba\ln a} + \mathrm{e}^{cb\ln b} + \mathrm{e}^{dc\ln c} + \mathrm{e}^{a d\ln d} \ge 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(ba\ln a + cb\ln b)} + 2
\ge 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{b+c}{\mathrm{e}})} + 2
\ge 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{8/3}{\mathrm{e}})} + 2 > \pi.$$

If $a \le 1$ and $c\le 1$, from Fact 2, the desired result follows.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: Let $f(x) = x\ln x$. Then $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}})$ and strictly increasing on $(\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}, \infty)$.
Also $f(x)$ achieves its global minimum at $x = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$. It is easy to prove the desired results.

*Proof of Fact 2*: We use the branch and bound strategy.

Let
$$\Omega = \{(a,b,c,d): \ a\in [0, 1], \ b \in [0, 2], \ c \in [0, 1], \ d\ge 0, \ a+b+c+d=4\}.$$
For $i=0, 1, \cdots, 127; \ j=0, 1, \cdots, 255; \ k = 0, 1, \cdots, 127$, let
\begin{align}
S(i,j,k) &= \Big\{(a,b,c,d): \
a \in \Big[\frac{i}{128}, \ \frac{i+1}{128}\Big],
\quad b \in \Big[\frac{j}{128}, \ \frac{j+1}{128}\Big], \\
&\qquad\quad c \in \Big[\frac{k}{128}, \ \frac{k+1}{128}\Big], \quad
d \in \Big[4 - \frac{3 + i + j + k}{128}, \ 4 - \frac{i + j + k}{128}\Big]\Big\}.
\end{align}
We have $\Omega \subset \bigcup_{i,j,k} S(i,j,k)$.

From Fact 1, we evaluate a lower bound $L(i,j,k)$ of $F(a,b,c,d)$ on $S(i,j,k)$, i.e.,
$$F(a,b,c,d) \ge L(i,j,k), \quad \forall (a,b,c,d) \in S(i,j,k).$$
Thus, we have
$$ F(a,b,c,d) \ge \min_{i,j,k} L(i,j,k), \quad \forall (a,b,c,d)\in \Omega.$$
With computer, we obtain $\min_{i,j,k} L(i,j,k) > \pi$. The desired result follows.
This completes the proof of Fact 2.

Comment: Nice answer +1, but I'm curious about how you used a computer to get this answer.

Comment: @IraeVid Thanks. The branch and bound strategy is to divide the domain into some parts, and for each part, we have a closed form minimum. Then just compare these minimum.

Comment: @IraeVid Honestly, this is not good. I believe there is a simpler proof by using some bounds such as $a^{ab} \ge 1 + ab\ln a$ and $d^{da} \ge 1 + da\ln d$ (assume $d = \max(a, b, c, d)$).