# Difficult inequality with $\pi$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

My question is about an inequality ,originally I wanted to prove this :

If $a,b,c,d >0$, and $a+b+c+d=4$, prove that $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da} \geq \pi.$$
from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774673/prove-that-aabbbcccddda-geq-pi)

My approach is to use this two inequality with the same conditions :

If $a,b,c,d >0$, and $a+b+c+d=4$,

$\frac{\pi}{2}(ac)^{abcd}\leq a^{ab}+d^{da}$

And

$\frac{\pi}{2}(bd)^{abcd}\leq b^{bc}+c^{cd}$

But I have no idea to prove this two last inequality...Thanks!

Comment: Probably it will be adequate the tag "number theory" here.

Comment: We can make something stronger: $a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}>3.16$

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg You surely direct the OP to $\sqrt{10}$...

Comment: @JeanMarie For $\sqrt{10}$ the starting inequality is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, could you post the proof of the original inequality?