# Power sum inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Today I have this to propose :

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be real positive numbers such that $a+b+c+d=4$ and $a\geq 3>1\geq b\ge c \geq d$ and $0\leq\varepsilon\leq d$ then we have :
>   $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da} \geq (a+2\varepsilon)^{(a+2\varepsilon)(b-\varepsilon)}+(b-\varepsilon)^{(b-\varepsilon)c}+c^{c(d-\varepsilon)}+(d-\varepsilon)^{(d-\varepsilon)(a+2\varepsilon)} $$

My try :

I want to prove that we have $f(\varepsilon)$ convex with :

$$f(\varepsilon)=(a+2\varepsilon)^{(a+2\varepsilon)(b-\varepsilon)}+(b-\varepsilon)^{(b-\varepsilon)c}+c^{c(d-\varepsilon)}+(d-\varepsilon)^{(d-\varepsilon)(a+2\varepsilon)} $$

And work with this but I can't go further .

Any hints would be appreciable

Thanks.

Edit : it's a conjecture but with the condition of the minimum I mean , $3\leq a\leq 3.3$ and $0\leq b\leq 0.5$ and $b\geq c \geq d $ we have the following refinement :
$$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}> \sum_{cyc}e^{\frac{-a^2}{2.55^2}}> \pi$$

@Simplifire Thanks for the invitation I will speak with you the next week if you want :) . And yes we are working on the same things . Have a good day .

Comment: Are you working on [this inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774673/prove-that-aabbbcccddda-geq-pi) by any chance? If so, please visit [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82585/thesimplifires-chatroom) as I have made progress with it as well :)

Comment: I have completed every case except for $a>1,b,c,d<1$ and $a>1,b<1,c>1,d<1$. Drop in a message (and ping me @TheSimpliFire) so that I know you're there. Thanks!